# CoreData objects not inserted

Tags: core-data

Insertion into `Core Data` suddenly stopped working.
I set up my `persistentStoreCoordinator` using the following code. Note that the `url` is `Spot.sqlite`.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Spot.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

I run the app, and execute

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications
find . -name MyAppName
A1DF7916-AE39-4367-BFD2-22A8BAA2AFD2
cd A1DF7916-AE39-4367-BFD2-22A8BAA2AFD2/Documents
ls 
(results) Spot.sqlite                       Spot.sqlite-shm                   Spot.sqlite-wal
sqlite3 Spot.sqlite
sqlite> .tables
ZMYCATEGORY   Z_METADATA    Z_PRIMARYKEY
sqlite> select * from ZMYCATEGORY;
```

and that shows no results, but I do get a line of output when I select the contents of `Z_METADATA`.

This is the code I use to insert an object in the managed object context:

```
+ (void)insertParentCategoriesIntoCoreDataFromArray:(NSArray *)array {
    ROAppDelegate *delegate = (ROAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *categoryEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ROCategory" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        ROCategory *category = [[ROCategory alloc] initWithEntity:categoryEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        NSArray *mySQLRow = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *name = [mySQLRow objectAtIndex:1];
        [category setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
    }
}
```

When I step through this code, it's executed as I expect. No errors occur. And yet still the relevant sqlite table is empty, and when I run the following code, I get an empty result set.

```
            ...
            NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name ==[c] \'%@\'", key]]; // the [c] means case-sensitive
            [request setEntity:categoryEntity];

            NSError *error;
            fetchedObjects = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to `save`.

I included this code and it worked:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[((ROAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
    // error                                         
}
```

Comment: Here's a tip: calling back into your App Delegate to get the managed object context makes you look like a noob. Pass contexts up through the stack. You'll find this makes even more sense when you start using multiple contexts.

Comment: Rather than passing context around the stack, create a singleton persistence controller to handle inflation of the Core Data stack and a getter that returns a scratch context to work with and possibly another convenience method to save the parent context as well depending on how you design your context relationships.